# Ubuntu Monospace Font

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-12.04, font-face

When Eclipse in Ubuntu is configured to use 'Monospace font', what exactly font file (*.ttf) does it use? I searched through /usr/share/fonts but couldn't find a font called 'Monospace'. I want to copy that file to my Mac OX and use it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

If the font is all you require, a quick Google search finds [this for fonts](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/monospaced)